# Pygame invalid syntax error can't figure out

Tags: python, pygame, syntax-error

I have been working on a simple game using pygame. I am getting this invalid syntax error and I can't figure out why. Heres the code that it highlights:

```
if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
      player.x = -= 1
```

It highlights the = sign before the 1.
And heres the whole code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pg = pygame

s_width = 800
s_height = 600

screen = pg.display.set_mode((s_width, s_height))

BLUE=(0,0,255)

player = pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLUE, (100,100,100,100))

main = True

while main == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit(); sys.exit()
            main = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                player.x = -= 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                player.x = += 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                player.y = += 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                player.y = -= 1


        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                player.x = -= 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                player.x = += 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                player.y = += 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                player.y = -= 1
            if event.key == ord('q'):
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
                main = False
```

I hope you can help! Thanks!

Comment: it's `player.x -= 1`

Comment: `player.x = -1` or `player.x -= 1`, but definitely not `player.x = -= 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change this line:

```
player.x = -= 1
```

with this:

```
player.x -= 1
```

`= +=` syntax is also invalid. You should change it as well.